# Virtual Sitecore User Group - Budapest #12

Tags: discussion, status-completed

### Topics

***1. SITECORE SYMPOSIUM 2020, 10 TAKEAWAYS***

> It has been nearly two months since the first fully virtual Sitecore Symposium kicked off on October 27th 2020. Whilst it was disappointing that we could not attend Symposium in person the upside is more sessions and content available online than ever before. Hours of talks, keynotes and roundtables from Sitecore experts all over the globe. And of course, plenty of new announcements from Sitecore on the direction and future of the platform.
> In this talk I will break down 10 key takeaways that those of us in the technical community should be paying attention to in our immediate work and looking forwards into 2021.

by **Nick Allen**, Sitecore Lead at Mirum UK, Sitecore MVP.

***2. DISCOVERING SITECORE 10 ASP.NET CORE SDK***

> Sitecore 10 released together with the brand new ASP.NET Core SDK, which is giving the possibility to implement Sitecore based headless solutions on .NET Core basis. In this presentation I am going to show you how you can use the new SDK and having a deeper look on the .NET Core rendering host architecture.

by **Tamás Tárnok**, Senior Software Developer at ALLWIN Informatics, Sitecore MVP.

The presentations will be held in English. Ask your questions or add your comments to the presentations while it's running. Streaming platform will be chosen soon and you will be informed! RSVP to the event to be up to date!

**When (UTC):** Thursday, January 14, 2020 6:00 PM

**Where:** RSVP to the meetup to join online!

**[RSVP to this Event](https://www.meetup.com/Sitecore-User-Group-Budapest/events/275171005/)**

Comment: Community Bulletin promotion began 14 hours ago